# Using Facebook's Flashcache on root partition (/)

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, flashcache

I'm tring to implement Flashcache for a root particion for an ubuntu box. There is an excellent doc how to do this in flashcache:

https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/blob/master/README-DKMS

My problem is at this line:

> Edit your /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.cfg to change the root device
>   to the flashcache device you intend to use

I'm not familiar with `grub.cfg`, how should I edit it? 
I can do the `fstab` part.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu systems you don't actually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but you edit `/etc/default/grub` which is well commented and even has its own documentation (`info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`).

But you can bet that you won't need to delve into "info" if all you need is to change stuff on the kernel command line (look for `GRUB_CMD_LINE_*` variables in that file).

Comment: *[and yes I hate "info" too]*